# My inline Javascript html is calling an external JS function, but the file is only running previous code. Why?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, pycharm

I created a Flask App using Pycharm.
I have an inline Javascript function `internaltest()` which is placed inside a html file. When I click a button, the function is supposed to call an external javascript function, and post an alert. For some reason, instead of running the current code in the Javascript file, it runs the previous code. (see below)

hom2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="/static/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='test.js')}}"></script>
<script>
    function internaltest(){
        externaltest();
        }
</script>
<button onclick="internaltest()">clickhere</button>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js (current version)

```
function externaltest() {
  alert("This is supposed to be running");
}
```

test.js (previous version)

```
function externaltest() {
  alert("This is NOT supposed to run");
}
```

I first ran test.js from hom2.html, which worked. Then I changed the alert from test.js and ran hom2.html again. Instead of alerting the new string, it alerts the one before I made the changes.

Directory:

```
app_code
   static
       test.js
   templates
       hom2.html
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you refresh the page?

Comment: Is the old page cached? Press CTRL + F5 (on windows) or add `?t=1` to the URL.

Comment: browser  loads `test.js` only once and it doesn't know that you changed something in this file - you have to reload page to load `test.js` again. To make sure you can also test it with `private mode` in browser.

Comment: Thanks, for your help,
I tried reloading and it still displays the old page. I have noticed that when I change the name of the file, it displays the current page. Obviously, this isn't a solution though.